# Why are my template areas not stacking as I expect?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

Using the following css:

```
.container {
  display : grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    'first second'
    'first second'
;
}

.first {
  grid-area: first;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  grid-area: second;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0eb5d6;
```

These boxes will stack (appearing as one red, 1 blue):

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
```

However, these will not stack, and correctly appear as 2 rows with the same css:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
```

In my actual use case I'm trying to align a form using css grid. I would like to not need divs for rows if possible. Or is this the only way to avoid stacking of elements into one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that here `grid-template-areas` *form a rectangle* and so `first` and `second` *spans* their columns. And multiple declaration will only overlap:

> A row is created for every separate string listed, and a column is
>   created for each cell in the string. Multiple named cell tokens within
>   and between rows create a single named grid area that spans the
>   corresponding grid cells. Unless those cells form a rectangle, the
>   declaration is invalid.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

You can *remove* `grid-template-areas` here - it works fine without it. See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.second {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0eb5d6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```